# How can I order the rows based on the abundance?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT     posts.id, posts.title, posts.body, posts.keywords 
FROM       posts
INNER JOIN pivot ON pivot.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = pivot.tag_id
WHERE      tags.name IN ('html', 'php')
GROUP BY   posts.id
```

It selects all posts that have tagged with either `php` or `html` or both of them. Now I need to add `ORDER BY` clause  to the query and sort the result based on the abundance. I mean I need to bring the posts that have both `php` and `html` tags in the top of result.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use table aliases.  It makes the queries easier to write and to read.  However, you just need an appropriate `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.body, p.keywords 
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     pivot pi
     ON pi.post_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.id = pi.tag_id
WHERE t.name IN ('html', 'php')
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) DESC;
```

Comment: OMG .. You answerd my question in less than 2 minutes. Bravo!

Comment: Just one thing, `t.name` has an unique index. So still you believe is `DISTINCT` needed?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . That depends on whether `pivot` has duplicates.

Comment: Has `pivot` duplicate on which column(s)? `pivot` also has an unique index on the `pivot(post_id,tag_id)` ..! Is `DISTINCT` still needed?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . Then the `DISTINCT` is not needed.